# $httpBackend not working fine with ngMocksE2E module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, angular-mock

I am making a simple application frontend with Angular JS (v1.2.16). I will be using REST API but that API is not build yet and its specs are complete. So based on the Link : [$httpBackend
- service in module ngMockE2E](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ngMockE2E/service/%24httpBackend), I can mock API request along with my development Process.

I have tried to do the same and come up with a [demo](http://ngdemo.ws01.tranceserve.com/#/projects) but its giving me an error where I feel that its failing for passThrough function.

demo is available on this Link http://ngdemo.ws01.tranceserve.com/#/projects.

Now it gives me an error stating :

> Error: Unexpected request: GET /views/projects.html
>   No more request expected

Please Help.

Comment: You should prepare a fiddle demonstrating the problem...

Comment: Due to several files, I could not find the way to create a fiddle. so I added it to a statc web server

Comment: You don't need to port the whole app to a fiddle, of course. You should create an **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org)**.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DQHdk/103/ : this fiddle works the way I want. It uses same versions of library I am using. It works here. But this same code doesn't works when I add this to my code, it stops working and gives me the mentioned code. You can View the Source of my app. I have used unminified files only

Answer (score 0):

$httpBackend isn't prepared to handle the request for the views. Add a passthrough for your views:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(/^\/views\//).passThrough();
```